# Is it possible to color only one side of a cube in PSTricks?

Tags: color, pstricks, rotating

I have this cube, implemented as follows:

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-ob3d}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-12)(10,10)

\rput(5,5){\psSolid[object=cube,a=1.75,action=draw,linecolor=red,name=A,opacity=0.4]
}


\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

And I want to have the bottom side colored blue. (How) can I achieve this?

Also, this cube is really not facing the right way, but it rotates around the wrong angle. I would like to have it facing the viewer, do you have any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 4):

The [`PS-Tricks gallery`](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Gallery3D/Gallery3D) has an example showing how to do this:

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}

\psset{viewpoint=50 10 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=25}
\psset{unit=0.4}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(10,10)
\rput(5,5){%
\psSolid[
  object=plan,
  definition=normalpoint,
  base=-4 4 -4 4,args={0 0 -4 [0 0 1]},
  fillcolor=blue!30,
  ]
\psSolid[
  object=cube,
  a=8,
  action=draw,
  linecolor=red,
  name=A,
  opacity=0.4
  ]
}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @stalkingisn'ttolerated True. Unnecessary packages removed. Thanks.